# Django-Haystack : How to limit search to objects owned by user?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have successfully made django-haystack with elasticsearch to work.
In the example below, I can search for any sales item and it would show up in the results.

I have created an Index:

```
class SalesItemIndex(SearchIndex, Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    item_description = CharField(model_attr='item_description')

    def get_model(self):
        return SalesItem

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

The model SalesItem:

```
class SalesItem(models.Model):        
    item_description    = models.CharField(_(u"Item Description"), max_length=40)
    company             = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_description
```

The problem is though, the user can search for all sales items, even those that don't belong to his company.

Usually instead of returning all `salesitems = SalesItem.objects.all()` I would rather use this to make sure the user only sees the items that belons to his company:

```
profile = request.user.get_profile() 
sales_items = profile.company.salesitem_set.all()
```

Would I be able to limit my search with this rule?

Answer (score 1):

You could index the company id in the `SalesItemIndex` as well:

```
class SalesItemIndex(SearchIndex, Indexable):
    ...
    company = IntegerField(model_attr='company_id')
```

And filter it directly in `SearchQuerySet`:

`sales_items = salesitem_set.filter(company=profile.company_id)`

Comment: This sounds promising. Is my assumption correct that I need to roll my own SearchForm in order to access the SearchQuerySet and do what you suggested?

Comment: @Kave if you mean `haystack.forms.SearchForm`, it supports `searchqueryset` in `__init__`. So something like `SearchForm(searchqueryset=sqs)` is fine. Also, I'd like to define a `get_searchqueryset()` method on the corresponding Django Model for convenience.